# How to use SURF on Opencv 3.1 in Java?

Tags: java, opencv, surf

I just begin learn opencv with java. So i have project (which means using Surf Detector) and i downloaded opencv 3.1. I found problem when i decided to compile code:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Specified feature detector type is not supported.) in cv::javaFeatureDetector::create, file c:\builds\master_packslaveaddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\features2d\misc\java\src\cpp\features2d_manual.hpp, line 155
```

How can I use Surf Detector?
I have read many pages about this problem and understood that, surf is nonfree. I downloaded opencv-contrib from git. But now i don't know how to compile this to java. Can i do this somehow on Windows? or is there compiled opencv contrib somewhere?
P.S. I'm beginner, sorry)

Comment: SURF on java is not available as of now.

Comment: Ref : https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/misc/java/src/cpp/features2d_manual.hpp#L355